# Wireless signal strength indicator shows low signals when actually signals  are good

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ralink

I'm running 12.04. Although my wireless connection is performing perfectly well, the Wireless signal strength indicator shows a low signal. Only the bottom bar is illuminated, whereas with Ubuntu 11.10, the indicator was fully lit up.

My wireless card is USB, and `lsusb` output is:

```
 Bus 002 Device 004: ID 148f:3072 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3072 Wireless Adapter
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

check signal with wicd, sometimes network-manager say crazy things like this, but I suggest both wicd and network-manager.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```